# Navigate another page after scan barcode

Tags: android, flutter

I've do many research on navigate another screen after barcode been scanned. But i still cannot found any solution...and i also got some message like this after the application has run the scan barcode function, example

1. E/libc    (15992): Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"
2. D/Camera  (15992): app passed NULL surface
   And I've also search for this kind of bugs or error...still cannot found any of it.
   Can anyone help on this? I'm just a beginner in flutter, your will be very appreciate, thank you.
   Here is the dart file.

loginscreen.dart

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:test_mcs/employeeConfirmationPage.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    
    class loginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const loginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<loginScreen> createState() => _loginScreenState();
    }
    
    class _loginScreenState extends State<loginScreen> {
      // Future<void> main() async {
      //   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //   var status = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
      //   print(status);
      //   runApp(MaterialApp(
      //       home: status == true ? loginScreen() : employeeConfirmation()));
      // }
    
    //===================== ↓ Barcode Scanner ↓ ===================================================================================
    
      Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
        // Set scanner as a string variable
        String scanner;
        // Platform messages may fail, so use a try/catch PlatformException.
        try {
          scanner = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
              '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
          // Display scanner result
          print("Scanner = " + scanner);
          //scanner = "9340";
        } on PlatformException {
          scanner = 'Failed to get platform version.';
        }
    
        //===================== ↓ Check employees's id from database ↓ ================================================================
    
        try {
          // Set map as a variable = Map<String,dynamic>();
    
          var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
          // Request action using "GET_EMP" from config.php
          map['action'] = "GET_EMP";
          // Request stfID = scanner result
          map['stfID'] = scanner;
    
          // Get response from server database with config.php
          final response = await http.post(
              Uri.parse('http://192.168.42.112/flutter/config.php'),
              body: map);
          // Display response get from database
          print(response.body);
    
    
          // If response status ok
          if (response.statusCode == 200)
          {
print("abc");
            // If response get from database = error
            if (response.body == "error")
            {
              // Set result as -
              setState(()
              {
                // _scanresult = '-';
                // _timenow = '-';
                // _shiftnow = '-';
                print('employee id not in database');
              });
            }
            else
            {
              // Set res as variable = jsonDecode response
              var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
              // print(res[0]["id"]);
    
              // Set result from what scanner get
              setState(() {
                // _scanres = scanner;
                // _timenow = dateTimeformat();
                // _shiftnow = timeShift();
    
              });
              //Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, 'employeeConfirmationPage');
              print('proceed to confirm page');
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/employeeConfirmationPage');
              //print('proceed to confirm page');
            }
          }
          else
          {
            // Display error
            print("Error");
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // Return an empty list on exception/error
          print(e);
        }
    
        // if (scanner != "-1") {
        //   setState(() {
        //     _scanresult = scanner;
        //     _timenow = dateTimeformat();
        //     _shiftnow = timeShift();
        //   });
        // } else {
        //   setState(() {
        //     _scanresult = '-';
        //     _timenow = '-';
        //     _shiftnow = '-';
        //   });
      }
    
      //===================== ↑ Check employees's id from database ↑ ================================================================
    //===================== ↑ Barcode Scanner ↑ ===================================================================================
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: Background(
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 550, left: 30, right: 30),
                  child: Text(
                    'Machine Checksheet',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 30, right: 30),
                  child: Container(
                    //color: const Color(0xff7a9dfa),
                    height: 300,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        // const Padding(
                        //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 190),
                        //   child: Text(
                        //     'Sign In :-',
                        //     style: TextStyle(
                        //         color: Colors.black,
                        //         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        //         fontSize: 25),
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 30, right: 30),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 70,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              elevation: 10,
                              onPressed: () {
                                scanBarcodeNormal();
                              },
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 179, 255),
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Employee',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 17),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 30, right: 30),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 70,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              elevation: 10,
                              onPressed: () {
                                //scannerScreen();
                                print(' Proceed to scanning');
                              },
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 179, 255),
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'Admin',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 17),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Background extends StatelessWidget {
      final Widget child;
    
      const Background({
        Key? key,
        required this.child,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: size.height,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child:
                    Image.asset("assets/images/top1.png", width: size.width * 0.51),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: -10,
                right: 0,
                child:
                    Image.asset("assets/images/top2.png", width: size.width * 0.51),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 60,
                left: 70,
                child:
                    Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png", width: size.width * 0.80),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: -15,
                right: 400,
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/bottom1.png",
                    width: size.width * 0.51),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: -10,
                right: 400,
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/bottom2.png",
                    width: size.width * 0.51),
              ),
              child
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

employee.dart

```
class Employee {
  String id;
  String empName;
  String empSection;
  String inchargeMachine;

  Employee(
      {required this.id,
      required this.empName,
      required this.empSection,
      required this.inchargeMachine});

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Employee(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      empName: json['employee_name'] as String,
      empSection: json['employee_section'] as String,
      inchargeMachine: json['incharge_machine'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

employeeConfirmationpage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class employeeConfirmation extends StatelessWidget {
  const employeeConfirmation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, left: 30, right: 30),
            child: Container(
              color: const Color(0xff7a9dfa),
              height: 300,
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 270, left: 30, right: 30),
                child: Text(
                  'Employee Information Confirm Page',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

generated_plugin_registrant

```
//
// Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars

import 'package:shared_preferences_web/shared_preferences_web.dart';

import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

services.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; // add the http plugin in pubspec.yaml file.
import 'package:test_mcs/employee.dart';

class Services {
  static const ROOT = 'http://192.168.42.112/flutter/config.php';
  static const _CREATE_TABLE_ACTION = 'CREATE_TABLE';
  static const _GET_EMP_ACTION = 'GET_EMP';
  static const _ADD_EMP_ACTION = 'ADD_EMP';
  static const _UPDATE_EMP_ACTION = 'UPDATE_EMP';
  static const _DELETE_EMP_ACTION = 'DELETE_EMP';
  static const _CHECK_EMPID_ACTION = 'CHECK_EMPID';
  static const checkResult = '';

  // // Method to create the table Employees.
  // static Future<String> createTable() async {
  //   try {
  //     // add the parameters to pass to the request.
  //     var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  //     map['action'] = _CREATE_TABLE_ACTION;
  //     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
  //     print('Create Table Response: ${response.body}');
  //     if (200 == response.statusCode) {
  //       return response.body;
  //     } else {
  //       return "error";
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     return "error";
  //   }
  // }

  static Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {
    try {
      var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
      map['action'] = _GET_EMP_ACTION;
      //print(map['action']);
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
      print('getEmployees Response: ${response.body}');

      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        List<Employee> list = parseResponse(response.body);
        return list;
      } else {
        return <Employee>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <Employee>[]; // return an empty list on exception/error
    }
  }

  static List<Employee> parseResponse(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Employee>((json) => Employee.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  // static Future checkID() async {
  //   try {
  //     var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  //     map['action'] = _CHECK_EMPID_ACTION;
  //     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
  //     print('checkID Response: ${response.body}');
  //     if (200 == response.statusCode) {
  //       response.body == checkResult;
  //     } else {
  //       return "error";
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     return "error"; // returning just an "error" string to keep this simple...
  //   }
  // }

  // Method to add employee to the database...
  // static Future<String> addEmployee(String firstName, String lastName) async {
  //   try {
  //     var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  //     map['action'] = _ADD_EMP_ACTION;
  //     map['first_name'] = firstName;
  //     map['last_name'] = lastName;
  //     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
  //     print('addEmployee Response: ${response.body}');
  //     if (200 == response.statusCode) {
  //       return response.body;
  //     } else {
  //       return "error";
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     return "error";
  //   }
  // }

  // Method to update an Employee in Database...
  // static Future<String> updateEmployee(
  //     String empId, String firstName, String lastName) async {
  //   try {
  //     var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  //     map['action'] = _UPDATE_EMP_ACTION;
  //     map['emp_id'] = empId;
  //     map['first_name'] = firstName;
  //     map['last_name'] = lastName;
  //     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
  //     print('updateEmployee Response: ${response.body}');
  //     if (200 == response.statusCode) {
  //       return response.body;
  //     } else {
  //       return "error";
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     return "error";
  //   }
  // }

  // Method to Delete an Employee from Database...
  // static Future<String> deleteEmployee(String empId) async {
  //   try {
  //     var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  //     map['action'] = _DELETE_EMP_ACTION;
  //     map['emp_id'] = empId;
  //     final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: map);
  //     print('deleteEmployee Response: ${response.body}');
  //     if (200 == response.statusCode) {
  //       return response.body;
  //     } else {
  //       return "error";
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     return "error"; // returning just an "error" string to keep this simple...
  //   }
  // }
}
```

The loginscreen.dart what i've already did is that try to print out any text on every line, until this line of code which "print("abc")" it do not show any text of what i want to print out. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get result of scan data after that use if else statement if the result data match to your data where you have to navigated if the data match then you will navigate to that screen else show some data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).